# How to run a raw SQL query from DataContext in EntityFramework Core

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

I have a `DataContext` instance that I want to use to execute raw SQL (if possible). I remember that "regular" EntityFramework 6 can do this (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109(v=vs.110).aspx) but I can't find any method on the one in Core. I've heard of the `FromSql` extension method (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) but that doesn't show up when do `myContext.myTable`.

Below are the references I have (image because I'm too lazy to type them out).

[image]

Comment: Please use correct tags in future. Your question is related to EntityFramework Core (that's where the DbContext comes from) and not to ASP.NET or ASP.NET core, since "in old ASP.NET" is just plain wrong. You can also use EF6 (the "old" EntityFramework) in ASP.NET Core if you target the full .NET Framework

Comment: Your references look fine. Can we see the `using` directives in your file? A simple `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` should do the trick to get you the `FromSql()` call.

Answer (score 1):

I realise that this is an old question, but here are some answers anyway.

You have 2 options, depending on what you are trying to do:

#### Option 1: DbSet FromSql

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
...
var sql = "select * from clients";
var clients = _clientDbContext.Clients.FromSql(sql);
```

Note that this requires you to have a Client entity matching the output of the sql statement and the related DbSet defined on your DbContext implemementation.

#### Option 2: Raw data access

```
using (var conn = (SqlConnection)((DbContext)_clientDbContext).Database.GetDbConnection())
{
    conn.Open();
    using (var reader = new SqlCommand(sql, conn).ExecuteReader())
    {
        ...
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

Now you have access to the raw DbConnection and the ADO.NET world and can use SqlCommand, DataTables etc to run any SQL and manage the data returned yourself.

I would caution you against mixing Entity Framework and direct SQL database updates - but this can be useful for picking up a small piece of data - maybe a config value, or running a stored procedure.